# ASC3 extending a custom class with MovieClip - gotoAndStop not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to setup a class that handles screen navigation for a game; called `MenuNavigation`. I have extended this class with `MovieClip` so I should be able to access `gotoAndStop` functions, but I keep getting the error -

> "1180 - Access of undefined method gotoAndStop"

. I have also tried:

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel)
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(frameLabel)
Stage.gotoAndStop(frameLabel)"
```

these do not work either. I have made a few other classes that have extended `MovieClip` would be this be an issue? is there a limit? Its weird I have done other flash projects and done the exact same thing and never had an issue. I'm sure its something stupid on by behalf. Thanks

Here is the code:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class MenuNavigation extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function MenuNavigation() 
        {
            // constructor code
        }

        // function deals with button navigation handling between frames
        public static function loadScreen(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
           switch(evt.target.name)
            {
                case "playButton":
                    gotoAndStop("aboutGame");
                break;
                case "creditsButton":
                    gotoAndStop("credits");
                break;
                case "aboutNextButton":
                    gotoAndStop("instructions");
                break;
                case "aboutBackButton":
                    gotoAndStop("mainMenu");
                break;
                case "instructionsBackButton":
                    gotoAndStop("aboutGame");
                break;
                case "instructionsPlayButton":
                    gotoAndStop("game");
                break;
                case "creditsBackButton":
                    gotoAndStop("mainMenu");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make the function static. Static functions are not in the same scope as the non-static members/functions of the class (i.e. `gotoAndStop`). Please read up some information about static functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function loadScreen(evt:MouseEvent)
{
....
}
```

Your main problem is with the scopes. The function loadScreen shouldn't be static. If its static the scope of the function is different and won't have the MovieClip object props and functions.